# How can I have variable redirection in a shell script?

Tags: shell, ash

If I have a script with the command

```
echo xx 2>&1 >junk
```

I get a file with "xx" in it. If I have a script with

```
R="2>&1 >junk"
echo xx $R
```

the script prints `"xx 2>&1 >junk"`, instead of creating the file I desire.
How can I have a redirection that is variable?
In the case at hand, I either want to do the redirection, or just
set the variable to the empty string to do no redirection. But I need to do it for a number of commands, so I would like to do it as a variable.
Note: environment is embedded Linux with an ash shell from busybox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use eval:

```
R="2>&1 >junk"
eval echo xx $R
```

BTW, if you want the stderr of the command redirected to the file, you must reorder the redirections.  `cmd 2>&1 > file` will print stderr to the original stdout, but `cmd > file 2>&1` will direct both stderr and stdout to the named file.

Comment: Thank you. Fixed my problem and caught a bug in one swell foop!